# What is the alternative of innerHTML to Speed Up the Webpage

Tags: javascript, performance, innerhtml, pagespeed

I'm working on a project and for that project I have created a custom dropdown international country code selection section, and for that I have injected all the SVG flag icons using innerHTML and I have noticed that after using the 240 lines of innerHTML the performance/ loading speed of my website is being negatively affected by the innerHTML.

**Please have a look on my JS Code -**

I have also read many articles on the internet that innerHTML is very slow but I have not found any alternative to innerHTML, could you please guide me a little with my JS code to improve the performance of my app.

**NOTE:** I have also a doubt that does the flag icon SVG are the real culprit behind the slow loading of my app? because that contains 239 SVG flag icons. Maybe this SVG icons takes time to render on my webpage. If this was the real culprit can you please guide me to optimize my code for faster loading.

```js
  // Autoclick on the parent div to hide the Dropdown after loading a page (Bug)
  window.addEventListener('load', () => {
      document.querySelector(".country-code-selector").click();
  });

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

      const head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
      const link = document.createElement('link');
      link.rel = 'stylesheet';
      link.type = 'text/css';
      link.href = 'https://amitdutta.co.in/flag/css/flag-icon.css';
      head.appendChild(link);

      // Get dropdowns and form
      const dropdowns = document.querySelectorAll('[cc-data-dropdown]');
      const form = document.querySelector('.country-code-selector form');

      // Check if dropdowns exist on page
      if (dropdowns.length > 0) {
          // Loop through dropdowns and create custom dropdown for each select element
          dropdowns.forEach(dropdown => {
              createCustomDropdown(dropdown);
          });
      }

      // Check if form element exist on page
      if (form !== null) {
          // When form is submitted console log the value of the select field
          form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
              e.preventDefault();
              console.log('Selected country:', form.querySelector('[name="country"]').value);
          });
      }

      // Create custom dropdown
      function createCustomDropdown(dropdown) {
          // Get all options and convert them from nodelist to array
          const options = dropdown.querySelectorAll('option');
          const optionsArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(options);

          optionsArr[0].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-afg"></span> Afganistan (+69)';
          optionsArr[1].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-alb"></span> Albania (+355)';
          optionsArr[2].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-dza"></span> Algeria (+213)';
          optionsArr[3].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-asm"></span> American Samoa (+1-684)';
          optionsArr[4].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-and"></span> Andorra (+376)';
          optionsArr[5].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-ago"></span> Angola (+244)';
          optionsArr[6].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-aia"></span> Anguilla (+1-264)';
          optionsArr[7].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-ata"></span> Antarctica (+672)';
          optionsArr[8].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-atg"></span> Antigua and Barbuda (+1-268)';
          optionsArr[9].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-arg"></span> Argentina (+54)';
          optionsArr[10].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-arm"></span> Armenia (+374)';
          optionsArr[11].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-abw"></span> Aruba (+297)';
          optionsArr[12].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-aus"></span> Australia (+61)';
          optionsArr[13].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-aut"></span> Austria (+43)';
          optionsArr[14].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-aze"></span> Azerbaijan (+994)';
          optionsArr[15].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-bhs"></span> Bahamas (+1-242)';
          optionsArr[16].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-bhr"></span> Bahrain (+973)';
          optionsArr[17].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-bgd"></span> Bangladesh (+880)';
          optionsArr[18].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-brb"></span> Barbados (+1-246)';
          optionsArr[19].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-blr"></span> Belarus (+375)';
          optionsArr[20].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-bel"></span> Belgium (+32)';
          optionsArr[21].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-blz"></span> Belize (+501)';
          optionsArr[22].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-ben"></span> Benin (+229)';
          optionsArr[23].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-bmu"></span> Bermuda (+1-441)';
          optionsArr[24].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-btn"></span> Bhutan (+975)';
          optionsArr[25].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-bol"></span> Bolivia (+591)';
          optionsArr[26].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-bih"></span> Bosnia and Herzegovina (+387)';
          optionsArr[27].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-bwa"></span> Botswana (+267)';
          optionsArr[28].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-bra"></span> Brazil (+55)';
          optionsArr[29].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-iot"></span> British Indian Ocean Territory (+246)';
          optionsArr[30].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-vgb"></span> British Virgin Islands (+1-284)';
          optionsArr[31].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-brn"></span> Brunei (+673)';
          optionsArr[32].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-bgr"></span> Bulgaria (+359)';
          optionsArr[33].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-bfa"></span> Burkina Faso (+226)';
          optionsArr[34].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-bdi"></span> Burundi (+257)';
          optionsArr[35].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-khm"></span> Cambodia (+855)';
          optionsArr[36].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-cmr"></span> Cameroon (+237)';
          optionsArr[37].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-can"></span> Canada (+1)';
          optionsArr[38].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-cpv"></span> Cape Verde (+238)';
          optionsArr[39].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-cym"></span> Cayman Islands (+1-345)';
          optionsArr[40].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-caf"></span> Central African Republic (+236)';
          optionsArr[41].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-tcd"></span> Chad (+235)';
          optionsArr[42].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-chl"></span> Chile (+56)';
          optionsArr[43].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-chn"></span> China (+86)';
          optionsArr[44].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-cxr"></span> Christmas Island (+61)';
          optionsArr[45].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-cck"></span> Cocos Islands (+61)';
          optionsArr[46].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-col"></span> Colombia (+57)';
          optionsArr[47].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-com"></span> Comoros (+269)';
          optionsArr[48].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-cok"></span> Cook Islands (+682)';
          optionsArr[49].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-cri"></span> Costa Rica (+506)';
          optionsArr[50].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-hrv"></span> Croatia (+385)';
          optionsArr[51].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-cub"></span> Cuba (+53)';
          optionsArr[52].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-cuw"></span> Curacao (+599)';
          optionsArr[53].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-cyp"></span> Cyprus (+357)';
          optionsArr[54].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-cze"></span> Czech Republic (+420)';
          optionsArr[55].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-cod"></span> Democratic Republic of the Congo (+243)';
          optionsArr[56].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-dnk"></span> Denmark (+45)';
          optionsArr[57].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-dji"></span> Djibouti (+253)';
          optionsArr[58].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-dma"></span> Dominica (+1-767)';
          optionsArr[59].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-dom"></span> Dominican Republic (+1-809)';
          optionsArr[60].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-tls"></span> East Timor (+670)';
          optionsArr[61].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-ecu"></span> Ecuador (+593)';
          optionsArr[62].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-egy"></span> Egypt (+20)';
          optionsArr[63].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-slv"></span> El Salvador (+503)';
          optionsArr[64].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-gnq"></span> Equatorial Guinea (+240)';
          optionsArr[65].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-eri"></span> Eritrea (+291)';
          optionsArr[66].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-est"></span> Estonia (+372)';
          optionsArr[67].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-eth"></span> Ethiopia (+251)';
          optionsArr[68].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-flk"></span> Falkland Islands (+500)';
          optionsArr[69].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-fro"></span> Faroe Islands (+298)';
          optionsArr[70].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-fji"></span> Fiji (+679)';
          // More 169 Countries (Currently not added here) -
          optionsArr[71].innerHTML = 'No Data Found';


          // Create custom dropdown element and add class dropdown to it
          // Insert it in the DOM after the select field
          const customDropdown = document.createElement('div');
          customDropdown.classList.add('cc-dropdown');
          dropdown.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', customDropdown);

          // Create element for selected option
          // Add class to this element, text from the first option in select field and append it to custom dropdown
          const selected = document.createElement('div');
          selected.classList.add('cc-dropdown-selected');
          selected.innerHTML = 'Tel-Code';
          customDropdown.appendChild(selected);

          // Create element for dropdown menu, add class to it and append it to custom dropdown
          // Add click event to selected element to toggle dropdown menu
          const menu = document.createElement('div');
          menu.classList.add('cc-dropdown-menu');
          customDropdown.appendChild(menu);
          selected.addEventListener('click', toggleDropdown.bind(menu));

          // Create serach input element
          // Add class, type and placeholder to this element and append it to menu element
          const search = document.createElement('input');
          search.placeholder = 'Search Your Country...';
          search.type = 'text';
          search.classList.add('cc-dropdown-menu-search');
          menu.appendChild(search);

          // Create wrapper element for menu items, add class to it and append to menu element
          const menuItemsWrapper = document.createElement('div');
          menuItemsWrapper.classList.add('cc-dropdown-menu-items');
          menu.appendChild(menuItemsWrapper);

          // Loop through all options and create custom option for each option and append it to items wrapper element
          // Add click event for each custom option to set clicked option as selected option
          optionsArr.forEach(option => {
              const item = document.createElement('div');
              item.classList.add('cc-dropdown-menu-item');
              item.dataset.value = option.value;
              item.innerHTML = option.innerHTML;
              menuItemsWrapper.appendChild(item);

              item.addEventListener('click', setSelected.bind(item, selected, dropdown, menu));
          });

          // Add selected class to first custom option
          // menuItemsWrapper.querySelector('div').classList.add('selected');

          // Add input event to search input element to filter items
          // Add click event to document element to close custom dropdown if clicked outside of it
          // Hide original dropdown(select)
          search.addEventListener('input', filterItems.bind(search, optionsArr, menu));
          document.addEventListener('click', closeIfClickedOutside.bind(customDropdown, menu));
          dropdown.style.display = 'none';

      }


      // Toggle dropdown
      function toggleDropdown() {
          // Check if dropdown is opened and if it is close it, otherwise open it and focus search input

          if (this.offsetParent !== null) {
              this.style.display = 'none';
          } else {
              this.style.display = 'block';
              this.querySelector('input').focus();
          }
      }

      // Set selected option
      function setSelected(selected, dropdown, menu) {
          // Get value and label from clicked custom option
          const value = this.dataset.value;
          const label = this.innerHTML;

          // Change the text on selected element
          // Change the value on select field  

          filterDate = /(<span\b[^<>]*><\/span>\s*)\w+(?:\s+\w+)*\s*\((\+[\d-]+)\)/g;
          selected.innerHTML = label.replace(filterDate, `$1$2`);
          dropdown.value = value;

          // Close the menu
          // Reset search input value
          // Remove selected class from previously selected option and show all divs if they were filtered
          // Add selected class to clicked option
          menu.style.display = 'none';
          menu.querySelector('input').value = '';
          menu.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(div => {
              if (div.classList.contains('selected')) {
                  div.classList.remove('selected');
              }
              if (div.offsetParent === null) {
                  div.style.display = 'block';
              }
          });
          this.classList.add('selected');
      }

      // Filter items
      function filterItems(itemsArr, menu) {
          // Get all custom options
          // Get the value of search input and convert it to all lowercase characters
          // Get filtered items
          // Get the indexes of filtered items
          const customOptions = menu.querySelectorAll('.cc-dropdown-menu-items div');
          const value = this.value.toLowerCase();
          const filteredItems = itemsArr.filter(item => item.value.toLowerCase().includes(value));
          const indexesArr = filteredItems.map(item => itemsArr.indexOf(item));

          // Check if option is not inside indexes array and hide it and if it is inside indexes array and it is hidden show it


          var options = itemsArr.length;
          itemsArr.forEach(option => {
              if (!indexesArr.includes(itemsArr.indexOf(option))) {
                  customOptions[itemsArr.indexOf(option)].style.display = 'none';
                  options -= 1;
                  if (options <= 0) {
                      customOptions[itemsArr.length - 1].style.display = 'block';
                  }
              } else {
                  if (customOptions[itemsArr.indexOf(option)].offsetParent === null) {
                      customOptions[itemsArr.indexOf(option)].style.display = 'block';
                  }
              }
          });
      }

      // Close dropdown if clicked outside dropdown element
      function closeIfClickedOutside(menu, e) {
          if (e.target.closest('.cc-dropdown') === null && e.target !== this && menu.offsetParent !== null) {
              menu.style.display = 'none';
          }
      }


  });
```

```css
 .cc-dropdown-menu-items::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
     background-color: #323757;
     width: 2px;
}
 .cc-dropdown-menu-items::-webkit-scrollbar {
     background-color: #323757;
     width: 14px;
}
 .cc-dropdown-menu-items::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
     background-color: #e8576f;
     border: 4px solid #323757;
     z-index: -1;
     width: 2px;
     min-height: 50px;
}
 #phone-number {
     width: calc(100% - 120px);
     margin-left: 120px;
}
 .frm div:nth-child(3) .inputBox .tx {
     margin-left: 120px;
}
 .frm div:nth-child(3) .inputBox {
     display: flex;
}
 .frm div:nth-child(3) .inputBox .ln {
     margin-left: 120px;
     width: calc(100% - 120px);
}
 .cc-dropdown {
     position: relative;
}
 .cc-dropdown-selected {
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center;
     width: 116px;
     height: 40px;
     padding: 0 20px 0 10px;
     position: relative;
     cursor: pointer;
     transition: box-shadow .3s ease;
     background-color: #323757;
     border-radius: 3px;
     font-size: 15px;
     color: #fff;
}
 .cc-dropdown-selected::after {
     top: calc(50% - 2px);
     right: 10px;
     border: solid transparent;
     content: '';
     height: 0;
     width: 0;
     position: absolute;
     border-top-color:#000;
     border-width: 4px;
     margin-left: -4px;
}
 .cc-dropdown-selected:hover {
     box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
 .cc-dropdown-menu {
     position: absolute;
     top: 100%;
     left: 0;
     width: 273px;
     border: 3px solid #323757;
     margin-right: -2px;
     border-top: 0;
     background-color: #fff;
     z-index: +9;
     margin-top: 10px;
}
 .cc-dropdown-menu-items {
     max-height: 200px;
     width: 270px;
     overflow-y: auto;
     overflow-x: hidden;
     z-index: +9;
}
 .cc-dropdown-menu-search {
     display: block;
     width: 270px;
     border: 0;
     border-right: 3px solid #323757;
     padding: 14px 0px 14px 10px;
     font-size: 15px;
     font-weight: 550;
     color: #fff;
     outline: 0;
     background-color: #323757;
}
 .cc-dropdown-menu-search::placeholder {
     color: rgb(214, 214, 214)!important;
}
 .cc-dropdown-menu-item {
     width: 267px;
     border-bottom: 1px solid #323757a6;
     font-size: 14px;
     font-weight: 550;
     cursor: pointer;
     z-index: +9;
     user-select: none;
     padding: 10px 18px 10px 10px;
}
 .cc-dropdown-menu-items .flag-icon {
     height: 15px;
     width: 26px;
     margin-right: 3px;
}
 .cc-dropdown-menu-item:last-child {
     border-bottom: 0;
}
 .cc-dropdown-menu-item:hover {
     background-color: rgb(228, 228, 228);
}
 .cc-dropdown-menu-item.selected {
     border: none;
}
 .cc-dropdown-selected .flag-icon {
     margin-right: 5px!important;
}
 .cc-dropdown-menu-item.selected, .cc-dropdown-menu-item.selected:hover {
     background-color: #323757c2;
     color: #ffffff;
}
 .cc-dropdown-menu-item:last-child {
     pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="country-code-selector">
   <form class="cc-form">
      <div class="cc-form-group">
         <select id="country" name="country" cc-data-dropdown>
            <option value="Afganistan"></option>
            <option value="Albania"></option>
            <option value="Algeria"></option>
            <option value="American Samoa"></option>
            <option value="Andorra"></option>
            <option value="Angola"></option>
            <option value="Anguilla"></option>
            <option value="Antarctica"></option>
            <option value="Antigua and Barbuda"></option>
            <option value="Argentina"></option>
            <option value="Armenia"></option>
            <option value="Aruba"></option>
            <option value="Australia"></option>
            <option value="Austria"></option>
            <option value="Azerbaijan"></option>
            <option value="Bahamas"></option>
            <option value="Bahrain"></option>
            <option value="Bangladesh"></option>
            <option value="Barbados"></option>
            <option value="Belarus"></option>
            <option value="Belgium"></option>
            <option value="Belize"></option>
            <option value="Benin"></option>
            <option value="Bermuda"></option>
            <option value="Bhutan"></option>
            <option value="Bolivia"></option>
            <option value="Bosnia and Herzegovina"></option>
            <option value="Botswana"></option>
            <option value="Brazil"></option>
            <option value="British Indian Ocean Territory"></option>
            <option value="British Virgin Islands"></option>
            <option value="Brunei"></option>
            <option value="Bulgaria"></option>
            <option value="Burkina Faso"></option>
            <option value="Burundi"></option>
            <option value="Cambodia"></option>
            <option value="Cameroon"></option>
            <option value="Canada"></option>
            <option value="Cape Verde"></option>
            <option value="Cayman Islands"></option>
            <option value="Central African Republic"></option>
            <option value="Chad"></option>
            <option value="Chile"></option>
            <option value="China"></option>
            <option value="Christmas Island"></option>
            <option value="Cocos Islands"></option>
            <option value="Colombia"></option>
            <option value="Comoros"></option>
            <option value="Cook Islands"></option>
            <option value="Costa Rica"></option>
            <option value="Croatia"></option>
            <option value="Cuba"></option>
            <option value="Curacao"></option>
            <option value="Cyprus"></option>
            <option value="Czech Republic"></option>
            <option value="Democratic Republic of the Congo"></option>
            <option value="Denmark"></option>
            <option value="Djibouti"></option>
            <option value="Dominica"></option>
            <option value="Dominican Republic"></option>
            <option value="East Timor"></option>
            <option value="Ecuador"></option>
            <option value="Egypt"></option>
            <option value="El Salvador"></option>
            <option value="Equatorial Guinea"></option>
            <option value="Eritrea"></option>
            <option value="Estonia"></option>
            <option value="Ethiopia"></option>
            <option value="Falkland Islands"></option>
            <option value="Faroe Islands"></option>
            <option value="Fiji"></option>
            <option></option>
         </select>
      </div>
   </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time you assign to `.innerHTML`, the entire DOM has to be re-rendered. So don't assign to each `<option>` separately. Create a single string containing all the options, and assign that to the `.innerHTML` of the `<select>` at once.

```js
// Autoclick on the parent div to hide the Dropdown after loading a page (Bug)
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  document.querySelector(".country-code-selector").click();
});

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

  const head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
  const link = document.createElement('link');
  link.rel = 'stylesheet';
  link.type = 'text/css';
  link.href = 'https://amitdutta.co.in/flag/css/flag-icon.css';
  head.appendChild(link);

  // Get dropdowns and form
  const dropdowns = document.querySelectorAll('[cc-data-dropdown]');
  const form = document.querySelector('.country-code-selector form');

  // Check if dropdowns exist on page
  if (dropdowns.length > 0) {
    // Loop through dropdowns and create custom dropdown for each select element
    dropdowns.forEach(dropdown => {
      createCustomDropdown(dropdown);
    });
  }

  // Check if form element exist on page
  if (form !== null) {
    // When form is submitted console log the value of the select field
    form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log('Selected country:', form.querySelector('[name="country"]').value);
    });
  }

  // Create custom dropdown
  function createCustomDropdown(dropdown) {
    let optionsStr = '';
    optionsStr += '<option><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-afg"></span> Afganistan (+69)</option>';
    optionsStr += '<option><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-alb"></span> Albania (+355)</option>';
    optionsStr += '<option><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-dza"></span> Algeria (+213)</option>';
    optionsStr += '<option><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-asm"></span> American Samoa (+1-684)</option>';
    optionsStr += '<option><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-and"></span> Andorra (+376)</option>';
    optionsStr += '<option><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-ago"></span> Angola (+244)</option>';
    optionsStr += '<option><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-aia"></span> Anguilla (+1-264)</option>';
    optionsStr += '<option><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-ata"></span> Antarctica (+672)</option>';
    optionsStr += '<option><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-atg"></span> Antigua and Barbuda (+1-268)</option>';
    optionsStr += '<option><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-arg"></span> Argentina (+54)</option>';
    optionsStr += '<option><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-arm"></span> Armenia (+374)</option>';
    optionsStr += '<option><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-abw"></span> Aruba (+297)</option>';
    optionsStr += '<option><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-aus"></span> Australia (+61)</option>';
    optionsStr += '<option><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-aut"></span> Austria (+43)</option>';
    optionsStr += '<option><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-aze"></span> Azerbaijan (+994)</option>';
    optionsStr += '<option><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-bhs"></span> Bahamas (+1-242)</option>';
    optionsStr += '<option><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-bhr"></span> Bahrain (+973)</option>';
    optionsStr += '<option><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-bgd"></span> Bangladesh (+880)</option>';
    optionsStr += '<option><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-brb"></span> Barbados (+1-246)</option>';
    optionsStr += '<option><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-blr"></span> Belarus (+375)</option>';
    optionsStr += '<option><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-bel"></span> Belgium (+32)</option>';
    optionsStr += '<option><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-blz"></span> Belize (+501)</option>';
    optionsStr += '<option><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-ben"></span> Benin (+229)</option>';
    optionsStr += '<option><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-bmu"></span> Bermuda (+1-441)</option>';
    optionsStr += '<option><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-btn"></span> Bhutan (+975)</option>';
    optionsStr += '<option><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-bol"></span> Bolivia (+591)</option>';
    optionsStr += '<option><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-bih"></span> Bosnia and Herzegovina (+387)</option>';
    optionsStr += '<option><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-bwa"></span> Botswana (+267)</option>';
    optionsStr += '<option><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-bra"></span> Brazil (+55)</option>';
    optionsStr += '<option><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-iot"></span> British Indian Ocean Territory (+246)</option>';
    optionsStr += '<option><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-vgb"></span> British Virgin Islands (+1-284)</option>';
    optionsStr += '<option><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-brn"></span> Brunei (+673)</option>';
    optionsStr += '<option><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-bgr"></span> Bulgaria (+359)</option>';
    optionsStr += '<option><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-bfa"></span> Burkina Faso (+226)</option>';
    optionsStr += '<option><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-bdi"></span> Burundi (+257)</option>';
    optionsStr += '<option><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-khm"></span> Cambodia (+855)</option>';
    optionsStr += '<option><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-cmr"></span> Cameroon (+237)</option>';
    optionsStr += '<option><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-can"></span> Canada (+1)</option>';
    optionsStr += '<option><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-cpv"></span> Cape Verde (+238)</option>';
    optionsStr += '<option><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-cym"></span> Cayman Islands (+1-345)</option>';
    optionsStr += '<option><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-caf"></span> Central African Republic (+236)</option>';
    optionsStr += '<option><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-tcd"></span> Chad (+235)</option>';
    optionsStr += '<option><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-chl"></span> Chile (+56)</option>';
    optionsStr += '<option><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-chn"></span> China (+86)</option>';
    optionsStr += '<option><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-cxr"></span> Christmas Island (+61)</option>';
    optionsStr += '<option><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-cck"></span> Cocos Islands (+61)</option>';
    optionsStr += '<option><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-col"></span> Colombia (+57)</option>';
    optionsStr += '<option><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-com"></span> Comoros (+269)</option>';
    optionsStr += '<option><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-cok"></span> Cook Islands (+682)</option>';
    optionsStr += '<option><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-cri"></span> Costa Rica (+506)</option>';
    optionsStr += '<option><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-hrv"></span> Croatia (+385)</option>';
    optionsStr += '<option><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-cub"></span> Cuba (+53)</option>';
    optionsStr += '<option><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-cuw"></span> Curacao (+599)</option>';
    optionsStr += '<option><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-cyp"></span> Cyprus (+357)</option>';
    optionsStr += '<option><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-cze"></span> Czech Republic (+420)</option>';
    optionsStr += '<option><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-cod"></span> Democratic Republic of the Congo (+243)</option>';
    optionsStr += '<option><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-dnk"></span> Denmark (+45)</option>';
    optionsStr += '<option><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-dji"></span> Djibouti (+253)</option>';
    optionsStr += '<option><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-dma"></span> Dominica (+1-767)</option>';
    optionsStr += '<option><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-dom"></span> Dominican Republic (+1-809)</option>';
    optionsStr += '<option><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-tls"></span> East Timor (+670)</option>';
    optionsStr += '<option><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-ecu"></span> Ecuador (+593)</option>';
    optionsStr += '<option><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-egy"></span> Egypt (+20)</option>';
    optionsStr += '<option><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-slv"></span> El Salvador (+503)</option>';
    optionsStr += '<option><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-gnq"></span> Equatorial Guinea (+240)</option>';
    optionsStr += '<option><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-eri"></span> Eritrea (+291)</option>';
    optionsStr += '<option><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-est"></span> Estonia (+372)</option>';
    optionsStr += '<option><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-eth"></span> Ethiopia (+251)</option>';
    optionsStr += '<option><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-flk"></span> Falkland Islands (+500)</option>';
    optionsStr += '<option><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-fro"></span> Faroe Islands (+298)</option>';
    optionsStr += '<option><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-fji"></span> Fiji (+679)</option>';
    // More 169 Countries (Currently not added here) -
    optionsStr += '</option>No Data Found</option>';

    dropdown.innerHTML = optionsStr;

    // Get all options and convert them from nodelist to array
    const options = dropdown.querySelectorAll('option');
    const optionsArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(options);
    // Create custom dropdown element and add class dropdown to it
    // Insert it in the DOM after the select field
    const customDropdown = document.createElement('div');
    customDropdown.classList.add('cc-dropdown');
    dropdown.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', customDropdown);

    // Create element for selected option
    // Add class to this element, text from the first option in select field and append it to custom dropdown
    const selected = document.createElement('div');
    selected.classList.add('cc-dropdown-selected');
    selected.innerHTML = 'Tel-Code';
    customDropdown.appendChild(selected);

    // Create element for dropdown menu, add class to it and append it to custom dropdown
    // Add click event to selected element to toggle dropdown menu
    const menu = document.createElement('div');
    menu.classList.add('cc-dropdown-menu');
    customDropdown.appendChild(menu);
    selected.addEventListener('click', toggleDropdown.bind(menu));

    // Create serach input element
    // Add class, type and placeholder to this element and append it to menu element
    const search = document.createElement('input');
    search.placeholder = 'Search Your Country...';
    search.type = 'text';
    search.classList.add('cc-dropdown-menu-search');
    menu.appendChild(search);

    // Create wrapper element for menu items, add class to it and append to menu element
    const menuItemsWrapper = document.createElement('div');
    menuItemsWrapper.classList.add('cc-dropdown-menu-items');
    menu.appendChild(menuItemsWrapper);

    // Loop through all options and create custom option for each option and append it to items wrapper element
    // Add click event for each custom option to set clicked option as selected option
    optionsArr.forEach(option => {
      const item = document.createElement('div');
      item.classList.add('cc-dropdown-menu-item');
      item.dataset.value = option.value;
      item.innerHTML = option.innerHTML;
      menuItemsWrapper.appendChild(item);

      item.addEventListener('click', setSelected.bind(item, selected, dropdown, menu));
    });

    // Add selected class to first custom option
    // menuItemsWrapper.querySelector('div').classList.add('selected');

    // Add input event to search input element to filter items
    // Add click event to document element to close custom dropdown if clicked outside of it
    // Hide original dropdown(select)
    search.addEventListener('input', filterItems.bind(search, optionsArr, menu));
    document.addEventListener('click', closeIfClickedOutside.bind(customDropdown, menu));
    dropdown.style.display = 'none';

  }


  // Toggle dropdown
  function toggleDropdown() {
    // Check if dropdown is opened and if it is close it, otherwise open it and focus search input

    if (this.offsetParent !== null) {
      this.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      this.style.display = 'block';
      this.querySelector('input').focus();
    }
  }

  // Set selected option
  function setSelected(selected, dropdown, menu) {
    // Get value and label from clicked custom option
    const value = this.dataset.value;
    const label = this.innerHTML;

    // Change the text on selected element
    // Change the value on select field  

    filterDate = /(<span\b[^<>]*><\/span>\s*)\w+(?:\s+\w+)*\s*\((\+[\d-]+)\)/g;
    selected.innerHTML = label.replace(filterDate, `$1$2`);
    dropdown.value = value;

    // Close the menu
    // Reset search input value
    // Remove selected class from previously selected option and show all divs if they were filtered
    // Add selected class to clicked option
    menu.style.display = 'none';
    menu.querySelector('input').value = '';
    menu.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(div => {
      if (div.classList.contains('selected')) {
        div.classList.remove('selected');
      }
      if (div.offsetParent === null) {
        div.style.display = 'block';
      }
    });
    this.classList.add('selected');
  }

  // Filter items
  function filterItems(itemsArr, menu) {
    // Get all custom options
    // Get the value of search input and convert it to all lowercase characters
    // Get filtered items
    // Get the indexes of filtered items
    const customOptions = menu.querySelectorAll('.cc-dropdown-menu-items div');
    const value = this.value.toLowerCase();
    const filteredItems = itemsArr.filter(item => item.value.toLowerCase().includes(value));
    const indexesArr = filteredItems.map(item => itemsArr.indexOf(item));

    // Check if option is not inside indexes array and hide it and if it is inside indexes array and it is hidden show it


    var options = itemsArr.length;
    itemsArr.forEach(option => {
      if (!indexesArr.includes(itemsArr.indexOf(option))) {
        customOptions[itemsArr.indexOf(option)].style.display = 'none';
        options -= 1;
        if (options <= 0) {
          customOptions[itemsArr.length - 1].style.display = 'block';
        }
      } else {
        if (customOptions[itemsArr.indexOf(option)].offsetParent === null) {
          customOptions[itemsArr.indexOf(option)].style.display = 'block';
        }
      }
    });
  }

  // Close dropdown if clicked outside dropdown element
  function closeIfClickedOutside(menu, e) {
    if (e.target.closest('.cc-dropdown') === null && e.target !== this && menu.offsetParent !== null) {
      menu.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }


});
```

```css
.cc-dropdown-menu-items::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background-color: #323757;
  width: 2px;
}

.cc-dropdown-menu-items::-webkit-scrollbar {
  background-color: #323757;
  width: 14px;
}

.cc-dropdown-menu-items::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #e8576f;
  border: 4px solid #323757;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 2px;
  min-height: 50px;
}

#phone-number {
  width: calc(100% - 120px);
  margin-left: 120px;
}

.frm div:nth-child(3) .inputBox .tx {
  margin-left: 120px;
}

.frm div:nth-child(3) .inputBox {
  display: flex;
}

.frm div:nth-child(3) .inputBox .ln {
  margin-left: 120px;
  width: calc(100% - 120px);
}

.cc-dropdown {
  position: relative;
}

.cc-dropdown-selected {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 116px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 0 20px 0 10px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: box-shadow .3s ease;
  background-color: #323757;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

.cc-dropdown-selected::after {
  top: calc(50% - 2px);
  right: 10px;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: '';
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  border-top-color: #000;
  border-width: 4px;
  margin-left: -4px;
}

.cc-dropdown-selected:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.cc-dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 273px;
  border: 3px solid #323757;
  margin-right: -2px;
  border-top: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: +9;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.cc-dropdown-menu-items {
  max-height: 200px;
  width: 270px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  z-index: +9;
}

.cc-dropdown-menu-search {
  display: block;
  width: 270px;
  border: 0;
  border-right: 3px solid #323757;
  padding: 14px 0px 14px 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 550;
  color: #fff;
  outline: 0;
  background-color: #323757;
}

.cc-dropdown-menu-search::placeholder {
  color: rgb(214, 214, 214)!important;
}

.cc-dropdown-menu-item {
  width: 267px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #323757a6;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 550;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: +9;
  user-select: none;
  padding: 10px 18px 10px 10px;
}

.cc-dropdown-menu-items .flag-icon {
  height: 15px;
  width: 26px;
  margin-right: 3px;
}

.cc-dropdown-menu-item:last-child {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.cc-dropdown-menu-item:hover {
  background-color: rgb(228, 228, 228);
}

.cc-dropdown-menu-item.selected {
  border: none;
}

.cc-dropdown-selected .flag-icon {
  margin-right: 5px!important;
}

.cc-dropdown-menu-item.selected,
.cc-dropdown-menu-item.selected:hover {
  background-color: #323757c2;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.cc-dropdown-menu-item:last-child {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="country-code-selector">
  <form class="cc-form">
    <div class="cc-form-group">
      <select id="country" name="country" cc-data-dropdown>
        <option value="Afganistan"></option>
        <option value="Albania"></option>
        <option value="Algeria"></option>
        <option value="American Samoa"></option>
        <option value="Andorra"></option>
        <option value="Angola"></option>
        <option value="Anguilla"></option>
        <option value="Antarctica"></option>
        <option value="Antigua and Barbuda"></option>
        <option value="Argentina"></option>
        <option value="Armenia"></option>
        <option value="Aruba"></option>
        <option value="Australia"></option>
        <option value="Austria"></option>
        <option value="Azerbaijan"></option>
        <option value="Bahamas"></option>
        <option value="Bahrain"></option>
        <option value="Bangladesh"></option>
        <option value="Barbados"></option>
        <option value="Belarus"></option>
        <option value="Belgium"></option>
        <option value="Belize"></option>
        <option value="Benin"></option>
        <option value="Bermuda"></option>
        <option value="Bhutan"></option>
        <option value="Bolivia"></option>
        <option value="Bosnia and Herzegovina"></option>
        <option value="Botswana"></option>
        <option value="Brazil"></option>
        <option value="British Indian Ocean Territory"></option>
        <option value="British Virgin Islands"></option>
        <option value="Brunei"></option>
        <option value="Bulgaria"></option>
        <option value="Burkina Faso"></option>
        <option value="Burundi"></option>
        <option value="Cambodia"></option>
        <option value="Cameroon"></option>
        <option value="Canada"></option>
        <option value="Cape Verde"></option>
        <option value="Cayman Islands"></option>
        <option value="Central African Republic"></option>
        <option value="Chad"></option>
        <option value="Chile"></option>
        <option value="China"></option>
        <option value="Christmas Island"></option>
        <option value="Cocos Islands"></option>
        <option value="Colombia"></option>
        <option value="Comoros"></option>
        <option value="Cook Islands"></option>
        <option value="Costa Rica"></option>
        <option value="Croatia"></option>
        <option value="Cuba"></option>
        <option value="Curacao"></option>
        <option value="Cyprus"></option>
        <option value="Czech Republic"></option>
        <option value="Democratic Republic of the Congo"></option>
        <option value="Denmark"></option>
        <option value="Djibouti"></option>
        <option value="Dominica"></option>
        <option value="Dominican Republic"></option>
        <option value="East Timor"></option>
        <option value="Ecuador"></option>
        <option value="Egypt"></option>
        <option value="El Salvador"></option>
        <option value="Equatorial Guinea"></option>
        <option value="Eritrea"></option>
        <option value="Estonia"></option>
        <option value="Ethiopia"></option>
        <option value="Falkland Islands"></option>
        <option value="Faroe Islands"></option>
        <option value="Fiji"></option>
        <option></option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Sir its not working with my code. can you please provide me the complete edit?

Comment: I didn't notice before that you were using `optionsArr` later in the function, not just for filling in the options. I've updated the answer to create it after assigning the innerHTML.